# This version of Gauge Intellij plugin only works with Gauge version >= 0.9.0

Tags: getgauge

I have installed Gauge version 1.0.6 on my machine and the intellij version 2019.2 with Gauge plugin version 0.3.16. While creating a new Gauge project i am getting an error as : Error adding module to project: This version of Gauge Intellij plugin only works with Gauge version >= 0.9.0 .

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed but a release has not been done yet. Please download the latest nightly plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7535-gauge/versions and install it. This may help fix the issue. Refer https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html for installing plugin archive from disk.

Refer : https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin/issues/392

Comment: I am still getting the same issue. I have to create a POC and its urgent. Please let me know the stable version of intellij and Gauge:                                              
1. which intellij version i should use                                                                                                   2. which Gauge plugin version.